# Scale multiple divs on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, loops

Okay, so I'm basically trying to achieve that if you click div1, the width of this specific div changes to 50%, and all the other divs their widths change to, let say 2%. (see jsfiddle for more clarity)

I've tried to do this by giving them a separate class, so the div being click is Online, the rest of Offline. I thought it might work if I then said something like; if .. hasClass .. do this.

In the end, I've managed to indeed scale the div on click to 50%, but sadly enough I made quite a mess of the rest. I'll include the code, and I hope someone can explain to me how I should proceed. I also thought of an Array but did not know how to move forward with this.

https://jsfiddle.net/6cjmshrq/

1

```
$(".sliding-panel1").click(function(){
  $(".sliding-pane2").addClass("Active");
  $(".sliding-pane2").addClass("Offline");
  $(".sliding-pane3").addClass("Offline");
  $(".sliding-pane4").addClass("Offline");
  $(".sliding-pane5").addClass("Offline");
  $(".sliding-pane6").addClass("Offline");
  $(".sliding-pane7").addClass("Offline");
  $(".sliding-pane8").addClass("Offline");
  $(".sliding-pane9").addClass("Offline");
  $(".sliding-pane10").addClass("Offline");
  $(".sliding-pane11").addClass("Offline");
});
```

2

```
$(".sliding-panel1").click(function(){
  if ( $(this).hasClass("Active") ) {
    $(this).animate({
      width: '9%',
      height: '100%'
    });
  } else {
    $(this).animate({
      width: '50%',
      height: '100%'
    });
  }
  $(this).toggleClass("Active");
});
```

3

```
$(function(){
    $('.sliding-panel1').click(function(){


             $(".container").children().each( function(){

              if (!$(this).hasClass('Active') ){
                $(this).animate({
                  width: '9%'
              })
              else {
                $(this).animate({
                  width: '50%'
              })                
};
```

4

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('Offline');
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    elements[i].style.widht='2%';
    elements[i].style.height='100%';
}
```

5

```
$(".sliding-panel1").click(function(){
      $("#selectedwhip").addClass("active");
    });

    $(function() {
      if ($("#selectedwhip").hasClass("active")) {
        console.log('active');
      }
      else {
        console.log('unactive');
      }
    });
```

Comment: you want that for the first div only or all should act the same ?

Comment: All should act the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can minimize the css your css isnt dry , just use a single default class for the default state and add a class with name `.Active` in css with the `transition` property and you dont have to write that much jquery code too to control the width and height, instead you add or remove the `.Active` class see a demo below if that is how you want it

```js
$(".container div").on('click', function(e) {
  var $this = $(this);
  $(".container div").filter(function() {
    return !$(this).is($this);
  }).removeClass('Active').addClass('Offline');
  
  $this.removeClass('Offline').addClass('Active');
});
```

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body,
html {
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: grey;
}

.panels {
  width: 9%;
  float: left;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: red;
  border: 1px black solid;
}

.Active {
  width: 50%;
  transition: 1s linear;
}

.Offline {
  width: 5%;
  transition: 1s linear;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="panels">1
  </div>
  <div class="panels">
  </div>
  <div class="panels">
  </div>
  <div class="panels">
  </div>
  <div class="panels">
  </div>
  <div class="panels">
  </div>
  <div class="panels">
  </div>
  <div class="panels">
  </div>
  <div class="panels">
  </div>
  <div class="panels">
  </div>
  <div class="panels">
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This looks incredibly clean. Thank you! On top of that; I have way less code to work with now. The adding and removing of the class in that manner makes so much sense. I wonder why I thought about it with so much difficulty before. Thank you so much for your solution!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is:

```
$("[class^='sliding-panel']" ).click(function(){        //selector part of class name
    $("[class^='sliding-panel']" ).addClass("Offline").removeClass("Active"); //for all  
    $(this).addClass("Active").removeClass("Offline");                         //for this element
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Slight adjustment of [Muhammad Omer Aslam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3731614/muhammad-omer-aslam)'s answer to account for shrinking the un-clicked divs instead of pushing them off screen (if I'm seeing it right):

script:

```
$(".container div").on('click', function() {
    $(".container div").removeClass('Active');
    $(".container div").addClass('Inactive');
    $(this).removeClass('Inactive');
    $(this).addClass('Active');
});
```

append to his css:

```
.Inactive {
  width: 2%;
  transition: 1s linear;
}
```

Comment: hey thanks for the heads up i was already editing it had it added as `.Offline` class as it was already used in the OP, thanks anyway